# Python relative imports within a package not on the path

Tags: python, packaging, pythonpath

How can I import a file that is in a parent directory within a python package (that is not on the path) into a file in a child dir?

I'm not totally clear on the vocabulary of python packaging so by way of example:

```
dir1/
    __init__.py
    runner.py
    in_dir1.py
    dir2/
        __init__.py
        in_dir2.py
```

dir1/in_dir1.py:

```
def example():
    print "Hello from dir1/in_dir1.example()"
```

dir1/dir2/in_dir2.py

```
import in_dir1   #or whatever this should be to make this work
print "Inside in_dir2.py, calling in_dir1.example()"
print in_dir1.example()
```

Given that `dir1` is not on the python path I'm looking for the best way to import `in_dir1` into `in_dir2`.

I tried `from .. import in_dir1` and `from ..dir1 import in_dir1` [based on this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python) but neither works. What is the correct way of executing that intent? [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) seems to contain the answer; however, I'm not quite sure what to make of it / how to actually solve my problem using [PEP 366](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)

Both `__init__.py` files are empty and I am on *v2.6*.

I'm attempting to do this without using any of the path hacks that Google keeps turning up.

Comment: Relative imports are bad, mmmkay?

Comment: add `dir1` to `sys.path` and use absolute import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the link you gave:

> Relative imports use a module's __name__ attribute to determine that
>   module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does
>   not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '**main**')
>   then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level
>   module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file
>   system.

You cannot do relative imports in `__main__` scripts (i.e. if you directly run `python in_dir2.py`).

To solve this, what PEP 366 allows you to do is set the global `__package__`:

```
import dir1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    __package__ = 'dir1.dir2'
    from .. import in_dir1
```

Note that the package `dir1` still has to be on `sys.path`! You can manipulate `sys.path` to achieve this. But by then, what have you achieved over absolute imports?

Comment: "But by then, what have you achieved..." nothing. This really doesn't seem like all that much of an edge case. I really cannot import within a package without sticking the top level on the path?

Comment: @Finn, it is an edge case because you are running a submodule of a package directly. While the proper way to do it would be to create a separate script that imports the package/submodule and run that.

Comment: what would the requirements be on the location of the separate runner script as far as pythonpath / location in the dir tree to make it work?

Comment: @Finn: `python your_script.py` adds its directory to `sys.path` therefore if you use absolute imports everywhere and `dir1` is along-side `your_script.py` then you could import anything inside `dir1`. [Why are my imports broken?](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#traps-for-the-unwary)

Comment: Finn, exactly what @J.F. Sebastian says. And then you *can* use relative imports in the modules inside your package.

Comment: relative imports would require `__package__` shenanigans

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, not in a module inside a package.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* actually do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

and that will work. But don't do that. It could break other modules.

I guess you could remove it directly after the import, but don't.

EDIT:

Actually, this also works and I think there's no reason it's not safe:

inside in_dir2.py you can do:

```
import sys
import os
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
indir2file=current_module.__file__
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(indir2file))+os.sep+".."+os.sep)
import in_dir1
```

Try hard to restructure your code instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen lots of people suggest run-time path hacks elsewhere (that's actually what I've used in the past) but everyone always follows up the sys path hack by saying "don't do it" so...