# How do I import my module?

Tags: python, import

```
/projects/mymath$ ls
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  mymath.py  mymath.pyc  tests
```

and under the directory **`tests`** I have

```
/projects/mymath/tests/features$ ls
steps.py  steps.pyc  zero.feature
```

I tried to import my factorial function

```
sys.path.insert(0,"../../")
#import mymath
from mymath.MyMath import factorial
```

But it said No module named MyMath.

Here is my dummy **`MyMath`** class.

```
class MyMath(object):

        def factorial(self, number):
                if n <= 1:
                        return 1
                else:
                        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

So what's wrong? Thanks. Is this even a good practice (editing the sys path?)

This will work `import mymath`

Comment: You can't import `factorial` out of `MyMath` because `MyMath` is its own *class*. You can `import` *top-level* objects from `mymath` being the module name. So you can do `from mymath import MyMath` and that's it. If you want to import factorial, then take it *out* of the class and then you can do `from mymath import factorial` (if you left it in `mymath.py`).

Comment: partial duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011545/python-relative-imports-within-a-package-not-on-the-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's right. There is no module named `mymath.MyMath`. There's a module named `mymath.mymath` though...

To be explicit, when you create a folder and put an `__init__.py` file in it, you've crated a package. If your `__init__.py` file is empty, then you still have to explicitly import the modules in the package. So you have to do `import mymath.mymath` to import the `mymath` module into your namespace. Then you can access the things you want via `mymath.mymath.MyMath`, and so on. If you want to import the class directly in, you have to do this:

```
from mymath.mymath import MyMath
```

And as someone else has already explained, you can't import a method from a class. You have to import the whole class.

Answer (score 4):

You can't import a function out of a class. You want to either import the class itself (`import mymath.mymath.MyMath`) or put the function at a module level and do `import mymath.mymath.factorial`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is your import is wrong. You have a package called mymath, and a module in it called mymath. In that module is a class. That's the most you can import:

```
>>> from mymath.mymath import MyMath
>>> myMathObject = MyMath()
>>> myMathObject.factorial(5)
120
```

The other problem is your second call to factorial should call factorial on `self`, otherwise it will try to look it up as a free function in the module, which won't work. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my dummy MyMath class.

Python is not Java; the class is not any kind of organizational unit here, but simply a blueprint for data types. There is no reason to define a class here (which would then have to be instantiated anyway); just define the `factorial` function as a function.