# Python eggs and relative import

Tags: python

I have a module that I pack as an egg with [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). I have a problem with relative/absolute improts.

The directory structure is the following:

```
setup.py        # using setuptools
mymodule/
 |- __init__.py
 |- mymodule_core.py
 |- utils.py
```

When I [easy_install](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyInstall) `mymodule` in the system from egg, this import works well:

```
# mymodule_core.py
from mymodule.utils import some_functions
```

But I want also to run `mymodule_core.py` from the command line, without installing it (for short tests etc). In that case, the previous import would fail, and this works:

```
# mymodule_core.py
from utils import some_functions
```

How to handle the `import` so it would work in both cases?

I guess that the proper solution would include `if __name__ == "__main__"`, `from .. import something` and `__package__ =` but I cannot make it work

Related:

- [Python relative imports within a package not on the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011545/python-relative-imports-within-a-package-not-on-the-path)
- [Python packages: relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059002/python-packages-relative-imports)
- [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to handle the `ImportError`, like this...

```
# mymodule_core.py
try:
    from mymodule.utils import some_functions
except ImportError:
    from utils import some_functions
```

...which would work fine in your case.

For cases where your package structure is such that a 'relative' import won't work, I tend to put something like this at the top of the source file...

```
import sys
import os

PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))
```

...then the `from packagename.modulename import symbols` syntax works either way.