# Python packages: relative imports

Tags: python, python-module, relative-import

I'm working on a Python application consisting of a core and multiple independent modules using the core. I'm having difficulty setting up relative imports of packages.

```
app
  |- __init__.py
  |- core
        |- __init__.py
        |- corefile.py

  |- module1
        |- __init__.py
        |- main.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty. I'm running Python 2.7.1.

```
main.py
from .core import *
```

Running `python main.py` results in `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Similar questions: [Ultimate answer to relative python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/), [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/), [Relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can only use relative imports from packages that are, themselves, imported.

For example, if you had:

```
$ cat run.py
from app.module1 import main
main.main()
$ python run.py
```

Then you could use a relative import in `app/module1/main.py` (although it would need to be `from ..core import foo`, because `core/` is one level above `main.py`).

Comment: That's made some headway, but now I'm getting `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`. Printing `__name__` yields `module.main` and not `app.module.main`. Why doesn't it see the directory above it as part of the package?

Comment: How exactly are you importing it? And are you importing it as `module.main` from something inside `app`?

Comment: I've managed to come up with a slightly tacky solution that involved trying different paths. I also call `module.main` from the top level, as you recommend, so I'll go ahead and close this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
abs_filepath = '/home/n/Documents/IMPORTANT/deep_learning/drori_2018/    final_proj/Ryans_branch/StackGAN/'
# insert your absolute filepath above as abs_filepath = '/path/to/targ/dir'
sys.path.append(abs_filepath)
```

Please correct it if there are problems with doing the `import` this way

#### Other Answers:

Also please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for a thorough answer about what's going on.