# relative imports in python for i don't know how many times

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, import

I have seen these sites:

[python relative import example code does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123062/python-relative-import-example-code-does-not-work)

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/

[Python packages: relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059002/python-packages-relative-imports)

[Relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python)

and loads more that I did not show, but they (The answers/The code) just don't work for some reason to relatively import other Python 'modules'. And for always, I have this forever-recurring error:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
program/
|_ main.py
|_ lib/
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ module1.py
    |_ module2.py
    |_ module3.py
```

In main.py:

```
from .lib.module1 import do_this
print('Imported')
```

In module1.py:

```
def do_this():
    print('I did it')
```

I'm using Linux to do this, but it just doesn't work!!!

EDIT:

I don't want to have to do `python3 -m <module> main.py`
And apparently it still does not work without the dot.

Comment: You've linked multiple answers explaining why what you're trying to do can't work, unless main.py is a module being imported as a module. Those answers say you can't run "python main.py" and have a relative import in main.py.

Comment: Either run it as a package / module, `python -m <module>` or just remove the leading dot and run it. If you run this as `python main.py` without the dot `from lib.module1 import do_this`, it will work. Otherwise the module is `__main__` and it can't resolve the relative package path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'll try your comment's answers on a different Linux computer @theherk