# Relative Imports & Directory Structure (Trillionth Time)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

## SUMMARY

I am fairly new to designing full-fledged python projects, and all my Python work earlier has been with Jupyter Notebooks. Now that I am designing some application with Python, I am having considerable difficulty making it 'run'.

I have visited the following sites -

1. [Relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python)
2. [Ultimate answer to relative python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/ultimate-answer-to-relative-python-imports)
3. [python relative import example code does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123062/python-relative-import-example-code-does-not-work)

But none of them seem to solve my issue.

## PROBLEM

Here's my repo structure -

```
my_app/
    __init__.py
    
    code/
        __init__.py
        module_1/
            some_code_1.py
        module_2/
            some_code_2.py
        module_3/
            some_code_3.py

        main.py

    tests/
        __init__.py
        module_1/
            test_some_code_1.py
        module_2/
            test_some_code_2.py
        module_3/
            test_some_code_3.py

    resources/
        __init__.py
        config.json
        data.csv
```

I am primarily using `PyCharm` and `VS Code` for development and testing.

The `main.py` file has the following imports -

```py
from code.module_1.some_code_1 import class_1
from code.module_2.some_code_2 import class_2
from code.module_3.some_code_3 import class_3
```

In the `PyCharm` run configuration, I have the `working directory` set to `User/blah/blah/my_app/

Whenever I run the `main.py` from PyCharm, it runs perfectly.

But if I run the program from terminal like -

```
$ python code/main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from code.module_1.some_code_1 import class_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.module_1.some_code_1'; 'code' is not a package
```

I get the same error if I run the `main.py` from VS Code.

Is there a way to make this work for PyCharm as well as terminal?

If I change the imports to -

```py
from module_1.some_code_1 import class_1
from module_2.some_code_2 import class_2
from module_3.some_code_3 import class_3
```

This works on the terminal but doesn't work in PyCharm. The test cases fail too.

Is there something I am missing, or some configuration that can be done to make all this work seamlessly?

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you do `python code/main.py` it makes your current working directory `code/`, which makes all of your absolute imports incorrect since Python doesn't see above that directory unless you explicitly change a setting like the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Your best option is to rename `main.py` to `__main__.py` and then use `python -m code` (although do note that package name clashes with a module in the stdlib).

You also don't need the `__init__.py` in `my_app/` unless you're going to treat that entire directory as a package.

And I would consider using relative imports instead of absolute ones (and I would also advise importing to the module and not the object/class in a module in your import statements to avoid circular import issues). For instance, for the `from code.module_1.some_code_1 import class_1` line in `code.main`, I would make it `from .module_1 import some_code_1`.

Comment: Thanks, Brett! Can you please elaborate - 'And I would consider using relative imports instead of absolute ones (and I would also advise importing to the module and not the object/class in a module in your import statements to avoid circular import issues).' That would be great!

Comment: @AdhishThite I edited my response to provide an example.